# FQN columns clash in HAVING clause - Unknown column error

Tags: mysql, query

Having this MySQL query

```
SELECT `books`.*
FROM `books`
LEFT JOIN `authors` AS `author`
     ON (`books`.`author_id` = `author`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `publishers` AS `publisher`
     ON (`books`.`publisher_id` = `publisher`.`id`)
GROUP BY `books`.`id`, `author`.`name`, `publisher`.`name`
HAVING (`author`.`name` = 'Writer 1')
    AND (`publisher`.`name` = 'Nextras publisher A')
```

result

> [42S22][1054] Unknown column 'author.name' in 'having clause'

(Those conditions are in HAVING clause because I combine them with another aggregation conditions, yet those joins are not necessary to reproduce.)

There is obviously an issue in the same column name between author(s) and publisher(s) tables. If I change the condition to filter by different column, it works. Similarly, I may add those columns to the select part and it starts working as well.

My questions:

- is this somehow intentional?
- is it documented?

I like to understand the behavior more before implementing a workaround.

MySQL: 8.0.24

Comment: Use `JOIN`, not `LEFT JOIN` in those cases since you the `HAVING` (or `WHERE`) insisted that the row exist.

Comment: My question is rather why is it happening, not how to workaround. This is simplified sql which obviously can be rewritten.

Comment: I'm hoping that the simplification will make the problem go away.  (No, I don't see what the actual problem is.)

Comment: I have also a tags table so something like: "select books that has not a tag OR has this publisher" results in this kind of HAVING clause `COUNT(tags.id) == 0 OR publisher.name = 'xxx'`

Comment: I should also mention this works in Postgres.

Comment: Is there some reason to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` (in this case)?  Sure, it is necessary for `COUNT`, but probably not for the other tests.

Answer (score 1):

A `HAVING` clause is a form of a `WHERE` clause, but for data that has been aggregated.

An example usage would be.

```
SELECT `books`.`author`, COUNT(*)
FROM `books`
INNER JOIN `authors` AS `author`
    ON (`books`.`author_id` = `author`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `publishers` AS `publisher`
    ON (`books`.`publisher_id` = `publisher`.`id`)
GROUP BY `books`.`author`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

However, you're not doing any aggregation in your query, thus you don't need a `GROUP BY` or a `HAVING` clause. Everything that is in your `HAVING` clause can move to a `WHERE` clause.

Also, as Rick James pointed out, consider an INNER JOIN instead of an OUTER JOIN, since your WHERE clause requires those tables have data.

See if this query runs and returns the expected results.

```
SELECT `books`.*
FROM `books`
INNER JOIN `authors` AS `author`
    ON (`books`.`author_id` = `author`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `publishers` AS `publisher`
    ON (`books`.`publisher_id` = `publisher`.`id`)
WHERE (`author`.`name` = 'Writer 1')
    AND (`publisher`.`name` = 'Nextras publisher A')
```

Comment: My question is rather why is it happening, not how to workaround. This is simplified sql which obviously can be rewritten.

Comment: @hrach Because you’re not aggregating anything and it’s in the group by. See the examples in my answer. Does the second query I provided work?